# Collapse geocoder plugin search box in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geocoding, api, mapbox-gl-js, css

How do I make my `MapboxGeocoder` collapse when not on hover? I am trying to make it like [this example](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v12.html?title=true&access_token=) (be sure to add your access token to the end), where the Geocoder search field expands when it's hovered. I was thinking it might require changing some CSS, but I don't know what to do to achieve that.

Here's my geocoder control:

```js
map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,mapboxgl: mapboxgl}), 'top-left');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/main/API.md#mapboxgeocoder) of mapbox-gl-geocoder plugin, there is `collapsed` option just for that.

So code could then look something like this:

```js
map.addControl(
  new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
    collapsed: true
  }),
  'top-left'
);
```